# JSON Path to extract first element from the search result

Tags: json, jsonpath

I'm new to JSON Path.

Note: I have already checked over some questions on SO, it's not helping me with my issue.

I have an example JSON given below :

```
{
    "phoneNumbers": [
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8888"
        },
        {
            "type": "iPhone",
            "number": "0123-4567-8910"
        },
        {
            "type": "Samsung",
            "number": "0123-4567-8912"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I have created JSON Path query which will bring all the json objects having the type as '`iPhone`' :

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type == 'iPhone')]
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "type": "iPhone",
    "number": "0123-4567-8888"
  },
  {
    "type": "iPhone",
    "number": "0123-4567-8910"
  }
]
```

After this, I want to extract element from the first index. That's where I got stuck.

I tried this query :

```
$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type == 'iPhone')][0]
```

But this query is not returning any results. What is the wrong with this query ?

Comment: @Tomalak This query `$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type == 'iPhone')][0]`  is not working. That I'm saying. What query should I use for my use case ? I'm running my query here -> https://jsonpath.com/  for testing.

Comment: Also I don't suppose you're planning to use https://jsonpath.com in production, so state what environment you're in.

Comment: @Tomalak I have edited my question. I have not used any environment yet. I just want to know what I need to use so that I can get the element from result array. I have provided everything that's required.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

[Filter expression return array can not use [index] get item inside](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272#issuecomment-264304891)

I'm not quite familiar with json path but on which platform do you run it?

Edit:
You need to define a key to the array because phoneNumbers is undefined

```
 {
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888",
    },
    {
      "type": "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910",
    },
  ],
};
```

Then the default query jsonpath.com

```
$.phoneNumbers[:1].type
```

outputs:

```
[
  "iPhone"
]
```

Comment: I have not used any used any environment yet. I'm using some online json path evaluator to test my scenario.

Comment: @AnishB. "some online json path evaluator"  Is it forbidden to share that location of the online evaluator?

Comment: No. No. I'm using this https://jsonpath.com/ to test. :)